# .css function Unexpected token ILLEGAL jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

for some reason in this code I am getting an error message
    $('#emailError').css({'display': 'block', 'background-color': #e35152});

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I don't know why

here is all the javascript.

```
function confirmEmail() {
        var email      = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var confirmail = document.getElementById('emailConfirm').value;
        if (email != confirmail) {
            $('#emailError').css({'display': 'block', 'background-color': #e35152});
             //document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
             //document.getElementById('emailError').style.background ='#e35152';
        };
    };
```

here is my html

```
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email *</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Confirm Email *</label>
       <input type="email" name="emailConfirm" class="form-control" required="required" onblur="confirmEmail()">
       <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">Your emails must match</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around `#e35152`

Comment: @MikeC thanks though its still not working trying to get a  span to show onblurr an error message if not same email and confirm email  any ideas

Comment: I guarantee you if you put quotes around it like what @kpucha suggests it will fix that specific problem. If you're having additional problems, try debugging it yourself then asking a new question on Stack Overflow if you're still having trouble with a specific issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6u7yLgza/1/   sorry here it is updated

Comment: Your inputs doesn't have ID so if you try to get an element with `document.getElementById()` you need to set the attribute id in the elements id="email" id="emailConfirm"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss the '' in the color:

```
//$('#emailError').css({'display': 'block', 'background-color': #e35152});
$('#emailError').css({'display': 'block', 'background-color': '#e35152'});
                                                              ^here & ^here
```